# Carrierwave: How to upload large files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, carrierwave

Use carrierwave
Upload files from 200mb.
Upload is long. The request to the controller lasts a few minutes.

How can I bypass this behavior?
How to add a file download in background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [bug in Rack](https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/1075). It will be fixed in the new release. For now, you can overcome this behavior by manually setting `Rack::Multipart::Parser::BUFSIZE` in one of your initializer files:

```
Rack::Multipart::Parser.const_set('BUFSIZE', 10_000_000)
```